# PostGIS - "COPY TO"

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, copy

I'm trying to create the function below using "COPY TO". The problem comes up here:

```
TO '/tmp/'||**NEW.gid**||'_gsv.html';
```

I need to use a variable for the filename **based on NEW gid value** but I do not understand how.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.long_lat_insert()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
        BEGIN
            NEW.long := ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(NEW.the_geom, 3763), 4326));
            NEW.lat := ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(NEW.the_geom, 3763), 4326));
            NEW.url := 'docs/googleStreetView/'||NEW.gid||'_gsv.html';
            COPY (SELECT '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll='||NEW.latitude||','||NEW.longitude||'" target="_blank">'  FROM public.p_work ) TO '/tmp/'||**NEW.gid**||'_gsv.html';
            RETURN NEW;
        END;
    $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.long_lat_insert()
  OWNER TO myuser;
```

So, how should I reformulate my expression?

```
EXECUTE ('COPY (SELECT ''<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll='||NEW.latitude||','||NEW.longitude||'" target="_blank">''  FROM public.p_work) TO ''/tmp/'||NEW.gid||'_gsv.html'')');
```

i get this error message-> [image]

Comment: Dynamic commands must by executed with an "EXECUTE" statement. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 1):

Like this,

```
EXECUTE FORMAT($$COPY
    (
    SELECT '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=%s,%s" target="_blank">'
    FROM public.p_work
    )
  TO '/tmp/%s/_gsv.html'$$, NEW.latitude, NEW.longitude, NEW.gid);
```

However, I would never do that. You're just trying to copy a single URL to a file. What's the point? I mean, even if it's a trigger and you need to do something absolutely certifiably horrendous like that. I would use [`NOTIFY/LISTEN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) with a client daemon. [(tutorial here)](http://bjorngylling.com/2011-04-13/postgres-listen-notify-with-node-js.html)

Or put an indexed flag on public.p_work for `is_processed` and have a daemon process it periodically (rather than slow down the inserts with synchronous IO).

Comment: And why would you think the database is the place to that? Notify an external script

Comment: The purpose of the function is to create for each point of the table an html file whose name is identical to the gid of the record and whose content is the code/url necessary for a view in Google Street View.

So i've changed '/tmp/%s/_gsv.html' to '/tmp/%s_gsv.html'

Unfortunately, it turns out a file containning not just a single line/single url but repeats the current url according to the number of records in the table:
<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=38.7110939840627,-7.89978155977766" target="_blank">
repeated line
repeated line

Comment: @josemvm just remove the `FROM <table>` part and you'll get a single line. But, I still feel the need to tell you that you're doing this wrong. You're brining a lot of sync-io in a trigger.

Comment: Thank you very very much Evan Carroll !!!

I believe this is not the best way but for now i don't know another better way...

Comment: Create a script in perl/python/ruby/php or best node. Have that script issue `LISTEN google_gid` and react when on the event. Then have PostgreSQL's trigger issue `NOTIFY google_gid, [gid];` Then the script reacts with the GID and does the async calls to google and writes out the file or whatever.

Comment: @josemvm http://bjorngylling.com/2011-04-13/postgres-listen-notify-with-node-js.html